# XIBs are not loaded for localization in app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, localization

I am using localization for english and french language in my app.

When I update XIB with `french` it makes two XIBs and it is showing its path to `fr.lproj` folder also in properties of that XIB,`Sampler/fr.lproj/MainWindow.xib`

It being made folders `en.lproj and fr.lproj` in different place for different XIBs as
for Mainwindow it is in `Sampler/fr.lproj/MainWindow.xib` for other files it is in
`Sampler/Classes/fr.lproj/About.xib`

But when I run the app is shows exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/3A0C67D1-F197-432A-9D9B-1086D0252E1C/Sampler.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''
```

what is wrong with this?

Comment: Have you added the localization to your project? In xcode 4, Editor->Add Localization.

Comment: There is an Editor menu at the top, beside the File menu.

Comment: Not Edit, 'Editor'. File - Edit - View - Navigate - Editor. Add localization will be enabled when you have selected your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the 6 steps [given in the link](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/) which are as follows:

1. Making Resources Localizable in Xcode
2. Localizing Interface Builder files
3. Collecting embedded texts into resource files
4. Translating the resource files
5. Importing the translation to the iPhone application
6. Testing the translation in an iPhone device

Answer (score 0):

Check your nib is enabled for the target you are building.